# Is there a way to configure Vim grepprg option to avoid waiting until the external tool has finished searching?

Tags: vim, grep

I am a long time Vimmer. However, I keep switching to shell to make searches. This avoids me to use the quickfix functionality.

The main reason for switching to shell is that when I use grep from inside Vim (with `:grep`), I cannot follow progress.

Because the code base I search is usually wide, I really appreciate immediate feedback.

It gives me a chance to find out that my search expression is wrong before the full results have been displayed.

This allow me to cancel the search, refine the expression then relaunch the search.

Any hint how to reproduce this pattern inside Vim would be appreciated.

Comment: do you know you can either make vimgrep really quicker by using noa and limit the number of search by specify a number ?

Comment: It is not an issue for me anymore: I am now under MacOSX Yosemite, and Vim 7.4. No idea when/what did fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the same vim behaviour as you. When I run `:grep`, I still see the results in vim (not in the quickfix) before the search completes (but I cannot do anything until the search is done).

I even tried using no vim settings or plugins:

```
gvim -u NONE -U NONE
```

If that's not your behaviour, check your `grepprg`. Mine is the default:

```
:verbose set grepprg
grepprg=grep -n $* /dev/null
```

---

When I use run `grep -e "score" -R /etc` I see this output in vim:

```
:!grep -n -e "score" -R /etc /dev/null 2>&1| tee /tmp/voLcaNS/232
```

It's possible that your system is missing `tee` or your vim doesn't use it (I'm using Vim 7.2 on Ubuntu 10.10). `tee` takes the text passed to it and writes it to a file and to stdout.

---

If you're looking for a way to have the quickfix get updated with your search results and have vim not block while you're searching, then you could write a script that:

- searches with grep as a background process and redirects to a file
- every second until grep completes, have vim load the file in quickfix (`cgetfile`) (you can tell vim to do something from another process with `--remote-expr`)

You can try my [AsyncCommand plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3431) to get your code started. It does the above, except that it only loads the file when the search is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [ack.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) at all? It doesn't use the quickfix window, but uses a separate buffer in a split. However, it's rather faster results come right back to the vim frame.

Comment: Ack is only faster than grep because it skips some files (e.g. binaries) and directories (e.g. .git) by default. Grep is just as fast (actually faster) if you configure it to skip the same things. Personally I put 'grp' on my path, which reads:
grep -rI --color --exclude-dir=\.bzr --exclude-dir=\.git --exclude-dir=\.hg --exclude-dir=\.svn --exclude-dir=build --exclude-dir=dist --exclude=tags $*

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to buffering between `grep` and `tee`, not vim itself.  To test this theory, run grep from the command-line and pipe the output through tee (i.e. `grep <pattern> <files> | tee temp.out`).  If it behaves the same as you observe within vim, then buffering is occurring.

To work around, install expect (`sudo apt-get install expect-dev` on Ubuntu 10.10) and grepprg to `unbuffer grep -n $* /dev/null`.  (See [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `:vimgrep` in the online documentation.  It displays the file name being searched and updates as it goes.

Comment: You only know it's doing something, you don't know whether it's finding any matches. (`vimgrep /gibberishdlgshjkls/g /etc/**/*` still returns filenames)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do a search in entire projects.

- System command grep(fast, but not working well with Ouickfix list)

  ```
  =>$ grep -n Example *
  ```
- Vim internal grep(slow, but have a strong pattern support)

  ```
  :vim[grep] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file} ...
  ```
- System plugin ack(perfect)

  1 install ack

  ```
  brew install ack
  ```

  2 add below configs to your .vimrc

  ```
  :set grepprg=ack\ --nongroup\ --column\ $*

  :set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m
  ```

  3 then you can use grep to call ack in vim like

  ```
  :grep "object\." app/**/*.rb
  ```